# ERF32 programming with SWD

Tags: swd, st-link, j-link

I need some help with programming board with EFR32FG22 ([Datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efr32fg22-datasheet.pdf)). I've always used arduinos or esp32/8266, so I'm new to this type of MCU's. I know that I should use SWD pins (SWDIO and SWCLK) which have testpoints on board I want to flash so it won't be problem, but with which device should i flash it? Will ST-LINK (v2) be enough or I must get JLINK, which is quite expensive? Maybe there are other options to write new software to it. I read that it **can** have bootloader on UART, but as far as I know [EUART or USART]? can be on any pin on this board. So i need help with finding out what is my best and cheapest way to have some fun with this board.